# Mystery: stored procedure inserting records at 1 record per minute

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

We have currently a mystery on our hands.

**The situation is as follows:**

1. We have a top-level stored procedure, which generates a list of dates for a cursor
2. In the cursor, another stored procedure is called with a date as parameter
   This stored procedure does a INSERT INTO whereby the date parameter is used in a BETWEEN statement in the query
3. The 2nd stored procedure executes through a number of dates, which goes fine, but due to the value of the parameter, no records are found
4. Once the date parameter is '2016-01-01 23:59:59', the 2nd query starts, but does not execute the query
5. The activity monitor doesn't show any activity, neither blocking nor any wait state. We waited several minutes, but the 2nd stored procedure kept running without doing anything (FYI: each run of the 2nd stored procedure takes about 40 seconds consistently).
6. This situation has already occurred several times before.

**Investigative actions:**

1. When executing the 2nd stored procedure by hand with this date parameter, it started, but did nothing (no blocking, no waits).
2. When executing the code of the INSERT INTO block with the parameter value of '2016-01-01 23:59:59', it executed successfully.
3. On a previous occasion we could successfully debug and execute the top-level stored procedure and the 2nd level procedure with the parameter value of '2016-01-01 23:59:59'. When clicking the 'Continue' button in debugging mode, it successfully ran through all remaining dates as well.

**Fixes:**

At that occasion we also managed to fix this strange behavior by renaming the 2nd stored procedure, and create it again. After that, executing the top-level stored procedure successfully called and executed the 2nd stored procedure with the same parameter values (all of them).

**Today:**

Today we had this problem again; we started the top-level stored procedure, it generated a date-list, called the 2nd stored procedure with each date, and when it got to the date '2016-01-01 23:59:59', it got stuck again (no blocking, no waits). 
When running the code of the INSERT INTO query with the parameter of '2016-01-01 23:59:59', we were successful. 
When we debugged the top-level stored procedure and got to the parameter value of '2016-01-01 23:59:59', the debugger went into the 2nd stored procedure, got to the INSERT INTO part of it, and exited. It did not execute the INSERT INTO query. In the debugger, the parameter values in the window where you see the parameter/variable values became empty, including all other debugging windows.
We restarted SQL Server, but to no avail.

So, this is our mystery. We're running SQL Server 2021 SP1 CU3, on Server 2008 R2.

If there's anyone who can shed a light on this mystery, we will appreciate this very much.

Many thanks in advance for your assistance.

Jan Willem Borrius

---

UPDATE: we now discovered that actually the 2nd stored procedure is inserting records, but very slowly: 1 minute per record!

We deleted the logging records for this stored procedure from the logging table, restarted SQL Server, restarted the process: now the 2nd stored procedure is inserting records at a normal speed.
However, we still don't understand why this is happening.

---

#

Resolved! Parameter sniffing, so we added to the INSERT INTO query in the 2nd stored procedure the following: OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)

#

---

Code 2nd stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XXXXXXXXX
   /* PARAMETER 1 */ @FIELD_2      DATETIME2(0)
  ,/* PARAMETER 2 */ @FIELD_1           BIGINT
  ,/* PARAMETER 3 */ @M_COD_SAT_ENTITY    NVARCHAR(100)
  ,/* PARAMETER 4 */ @FIELD_3       BIGINT
  ,/* PARAMETER 5 */ @M_COD_INSTANCE      BIGINT

AS
DECLARE @LOG    VARCHAR(200)
-- BEGIN: BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRY

PRINT @FIELD_2


INSERT INTO XXXXXXXX
       (
       [FIELD_1],
       [FIELD_2],
       [FIELD_3],
       [FIELD_4],
      [FIELD_5],
       [FIELD_6]      ,              -- [DT_ID]
       [FIELD_7]      ,                  -- [DP_ID]
       [FIELD_8]      ,                  -- [KOA_ID]
       [FIELD_9]      ,                      -- [KO_ID]
       [FIELD_10]      ,                 -- [PDI_ID]
       [FIELD_11]      ,                 -- [LBI_ID]
       [FIELD_12],
       [FIELD_13],
       [FIELD_14],
       [FIELD_15],
       [FIELD_16],
       [FIELD_17],
       [FIELD_18],
       [FIELD_19],
       [FIELD_20],
       [FIELD_21],
       [FIELD_22],
       [FIELD_23],
       [FIELD_24],
       [FIELD_25],
       [FIELD_26],
       [FIELD_27],
       [FIELD_28],
       [FIELD_29],
       [FIELD_30],
       [FIELD_31],
       [FIELD_32],
       [FIELD_33],
       [FIELD_34],
       [FIELD_35],
       [FIELD_36],
       [FIELD_37],
       [FIELD_38],
       [FIELD_39],
       [FIELD_40],
       [FIELD_41],
       [FIELD_42],
       [FIELD_43],
       [FIELD_44],
       [FIELD_45],
       [FIELD_46]
       )
       SELECT 
              @FIELD_1 [FIELD_1],
              @FIELD_2 [FIELD_2],
              @FIELD_3 [FIELD_3],
              BINARY_CHECKSUM(HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT( VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_13]))                 --FIELD_4
              , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_14]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_15]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_22]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_23]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_24]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_25]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_26]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_27]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_28]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_29]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_30]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_31]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_32]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_33]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_34]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_35]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_36]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_37]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_38]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_39]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_40]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_41]))
            , HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [KC].[FIELD_42]))
            ) [FIELD_4],
            [KC].[FIELD_5],
              [KC].[FIELD_6]      ,             -- [DT_ID]
              [SCDD].[FIELD_9] AS [FIELD_7]      , -- [DP_ID]
              [KC].[FIELD_9] AS [FIELD_8]      ,  -- [KOA_ID]
              [KC].[FIELD_9]      ,                 -- [KO_ID]
              [LPDI].[M_FIELD_10]      ,            -- [PDI_ID]
              [HVM].[M_FIELD_11]      ,         -- [LBI_ID]
              1 AS [FIELD_12]      ,

              -- Feiten voor FIELD_4
              [KC].[FIELD_13],
              [KC].[FIELD_14],
              CASE
                  WHEN [KC].[FIELD_15] > 0
                  THEN [KC].[FIELD_15]
                  ELSE 0
              END AS [FIELD_15]      ,


              CASE
                  WHEN [KC].[FIELD_15] < 0
                  THEN-1 * [KC].[FIELD_15]
                  ELSE 0
              END AS [FIELD_16],
              0 [FIELD_17]      ,

              CASE
                  WHEN [KC].[FIELD_15] > 0
                  THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
              END AS [FIELD_18],
              CASE
                  WHEN [KC].[FIELD_22] NOT IN('T', 'S', 'W')
                  THEN DATEDIFF([D], [KC].[FIELD_6], @FIELD_2)
                  ELSE NULL
              END AS [FIELD_19],
              CASE
                  WHEN [KC].[FIELD_22] NOT IN('T', 'S', 'W')
                  THEN DATEDIFF([M], [KC].[FIELD_6], @FIELD_2)
                  ELSE NULL
              END AS [FIELD_20],
              CASE
                  WHEN [KC].[FIELD_14] > 0
                  THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
              END AS [FIELD_21]      ,
              [KC].[FIELD_22],
              [KC].[FIELD_23],
              [KC].[FIELD_24],
              [KC].[FIELD_25],
              [KC].[FIELD_26],
              [KC].[FIELD_27],
              [KC].[FIELD_28],
              [KC].[FIELD_29],
              [KC].[FIELD_30],
              [KC].[FIELD_31],
              [KC].[FIELD_32],
              [KC].[FIELD_33],
              [KC].[FIELD_34],
              [KC].[FIELD_35],
              [KC].[FIELD_36],
              [KC].[FIELD_37],
              [KC].[FIELD_38],
              [KC].[FIELD_39],
              [KC].[FIELD_40],
              [KC].[FIELD_41],
              [KC].[FIELD_42],
              NULL AS [FIELD_43]    ,
              CONVERT(         NUMERIC(6, 1), [IAPR]) AS [FIELD_44]    ,
              CONVERT(         NUMERIC(6, 3), (POWER(1.000000 + ([IAPR] / 100), 1.00000000 / 12.000000) - 1) * 100) AS [FIELD_45]    ,
              CONVERT(         NUMERIC(6, 1), ((POWER(1.000000 + ([IAPR] / 100), 1.00000000 / 12.000000) - 1) * 100) * 12) AS [FIELD_46]


       FROM [SCHEMA_1].[TABLE_1] [KC] 
            LEFT JOIN [DATABASE_1].[SCHEMA_1].[TABLE_2] [HCD]
            ON [HCD].[FIELD_47] = [KC].[FIELD_47]
               AND [HCD].[FIELD_48] = 3001
               AND FIELD_2 BETWEEN [HCD].[FIELD_52] AND [HCD].[FIELD_53] 
            LEFT JOIN [DATABASE_1].[SCHEMA_2].[TABLE_3] [LCC]
            ON [HCD].[FIELD_50] = [LCC].[FIELD_50]
               AND [LCC].[FIELD_51] = 186
               AND FIELD_2 BETWEEN [LCC].[FIELD_52] AND [LCC].[FIELD_53] 
            LEFT JOIN [DATABASE_1].[SCHEMA_2].[TABLE_4] [HCD2]
            ON [HCD2].[FIELD_50] = [LCC].[FIELD_50_2]
               AND [HCD2].[FIELD_48] = 3005
               AND FIELD_2 BETWEEN [HCD2].[FIELD_52] AND [HCD2].[FIELD_53] 
            LEFT JOIN [SCHEMA_1].[TABLE_5] [SCDD]
            ON [SCDD].[FIELD_50] = [HCD].[FIELD_50]
               AND FIELD_2 BETWEEN [SCDD].[FIELD_52] AND [SCDD].[FIELD_53] 
            LEFT JOIN [SCHEMA_2].[TABLE_6] [LPDI]
            ON [LPDI].[FIELD_50] = [KC].[FIELD_50]
               AND FIELD_2 BETWEEN [LPDI].[FIELD_52] AND [LPDI].[FIELD_53]
               AND [LPDI].[FIELD_51] = 184 
            LEFT JOIN [SCHEMA_2].[TABLE_7] [LVMS]
            ON [LVMS].[FIELD_50] = [KC].[FIELD_50]
               AND FIELD_2 BETWEEN [LVMS].[FIELD_52] AND [LVMS].[FIELD_53]
               AND [LVMS].[FIELD_51] = 192 
            LEFT JOIN [SCHEMA_2].[TABLE_8] [HVMS]
            ON [HVMS].[FIELD_55] = [LVMS].[FIELD_55]
               AND FIELD_2 BETWEEN [HVMS].[FIELD_52] AND [HVMS].[FIELD_53]
               AND [HVMS].[FIELD_48] = 1100 
            LEFT JOIN [SCHEMA_2].[TABLE_9] [LVM]
            ON [LVM].[FIELD_55_1] = [LVMS].[FIELD_55]
               AND FIELD_2 BETWEEN [LVM].[FIELD_52] AND [LVM].[FIELD_53]
               AND [LVM].[FIELD_51] = 181 
            LEFT JOIN [SCHEMA_2].[TABLE_10] [HVM]
            ON [HVM].[FIELD_55] = [LVM].[FIELD_55_2]
               AND FIELD_2 BETWEEN [HVM].[FIELD_52] AND [HVM].[FIELD_53]
               AND [HVM].[FIELD_48] = 1110 
            LEFT JOIN [SCHEMA_3].[TABLE_11] [I]
            ON [I].[ISERL] = [KC].[FIELD_56]
               AND FIELD_2 BETWEEN [I].[FIELD_52] AND [I].[FIELD_53]
       WHERE 
       FIELD_2 BETWEEN [KC].[FIELD_52] AND [KC].[FIELD_53];

SET @LOG = 'SF_PROCESS_SNAPSHOT(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@FIELD_2) + ') inserted :'  + convert(varchar,@@ROWCOUNT)  


EXECUTE XXX.XXX 
/* PAR 1 */  @FIELD_3
/* PAR 2 */ ,@M_COD_INSTANCE
/* PAR 3 */ ,'INFORMATION'
/* PAR 4 */ ,@LOG
-- END INSERT LOG

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
  SET @LOG = ERROR_MESSAGE()
  EXECUTE XXX.XXX
/* PAR 1 */  @FIELD_3
/* PAR 2 */ ,@M_COD_INSTANCE
/* PAR 3 */ ,'ERROR'
/* PAR 4 */ ,@LOG
END CATCH 



GO
```

Comment: Is there any trigger in this table, any constraint?

Comment: Could you post the second SP?

Comment: Seeing the actual code would be good.  Could it be a transaction issue?  I had a problem where actions appeared to occur (code was executed) but no change happened to the database.  It turned out that a transaction was started on the connection but not stopped when an error occurred.  Subsequent actions were done as normal on the connection and appeared to work.  However the original transaction eventually was rolled back and all work lost.

Comment: Could it be an endless loop? since you are looping through dates with times. Another avenue of investigation which will confirm this is using SQL Profiler to trace the stored procedure.

Comment: No, it's not an endless loop, the top-level stored procedure has a cursor with a list of dates.

Comment: No, there is no trigger in this table

Comment: We do not use BEGIN TRAN ... COMMIT TRAN

Comment: I don't see any reason for this needing to be across two stored procs. It appears that you could just join to your date list and run one SQL. Anyway, at this stage you need to inspect the procs with SQL Profiler and see which statement it is getting internally stuck on.

Comment: Parameter sniffing issue?

Comment: Many thanks for the edits!

Comment: It was parameter sniffing! To the INSERT INTO query in 2nd stored procedure we added: OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)